# In DB2 for LUW, can I return all associated rows in a join if only one row matches

Tags: sql, db2, one-to-many

Let's say we have Table A and Table B. Technically, this is a many-to-many relationship. One entry in A can be associated to multiple entries in B, and vice versa. My issue arises when I have a subquery that returns a set of B entries. These are matched to A, but I would also like to get ALL entries in B that are associated to A, which is likely a superset of the subquery. As a result, I have to join A back to B. It should be noted that I need information from both A and B to be returned, which excludes a number of possible techniques.

What I'd like to do is start with A, join to B, and then filter with the subquery in such a way that if an entry in B is matched in the subquery, then ALL entries in B associated to the entry in A will be returned.

For example, let's say entry A1 is associated to B1, B2, and B3. If our subquery contains B1 and we join from B to A, then we'll get one row with A1 and B1. If we join back to B, we can get A1 with B1, B2, and B3 in three rows. What I'd like to do is find a function, expression, etc that can join A to B, then see that B1 is in the subquery and that B1 is associated to A1, so all rows for A1 are returned and we get B1, B2, and B3 in three rows. If A2 is associated to B4 and B5 and neither of them are included in the subquery, then A2 should be excluded from the results. Basically, one hit in the association returns all rows for the association. In this way we can treat it as a one-to-many relationship from A to B.

To diagram it:

```
A   |   B
----------
A1  |   B1
A1  |   B2
A1  |   B3
A2  |   B4
A2  |   B5
```

Where A1 and B1, B2, and B3 are both keys (and are actually two columns of randomly-generated bigints, but this simplifies things a bit) that are present as foreign keys in the other table. In the first example:

```
WITH SUB (ID) AS (Subquery)
SELECT bb.*, aa.*
FROM SUB
JOIN B bb
ON bb.OTHER_ID = SUB.ID
JOIN A aa
ON bb.ID = aa.ID
```

Which, when the subquery returns B1, will give us:

```
A   |   B
----------
A1  |   B1
```

Now, if we append this to the query and change the SELECT to aa.*, bb2.*:

```
JOIN B bb2
ON aa.ID = bb2.ID
```

Then we get all rows for A1 as seen in the first example table. However, this requires joining back to B, which I would like to avoid. Also note that the subquery does NOT return B.ID, but a separate identifier, B.OTHER_ID. Instead, consider this:

```
SELECT aa.*, bb.*
FROM A aa
JOIN B bb
ON aa.ID = bb.ID
WHERE
--Insert function here that will take the subquery, and if any row in B 
--is present in the set returned by the subquery, then ALL rows in A that include 
--at least one matching row will be returned with all related rows in B
```

This is a simplification of what I'm actually trying to do, but the reason is that it's simply to expensive for me to join B to A, then A to B again (there are a few tables in between due to normalization). Is there a way to do this by only joining A to B or am I wishing for something that doesn't exist? I'm not looking to rewrite the query to enhance readability. I'm just looking for a way to logically process the relationship to reduce the number of necessary joins.

Sorry for asking this more than once, but I don't think I've been able to quite convey properly what I'm trying to do. Maybe it just isn't possible.

Comment: How are TableA and TableB associated? A common id or an xref table or...? The example may be clearer with table schemas and some concrete test data.

Comment: True. They are associated by ID, but there are a couple of intermediary tables due to normalization that are linked together via primary key/foreign key. They contain no data relevant to the result set I need, but they're there nonetheless. The example is simplified to two directly-linked tables.

Comment: Yes, a set of 'actual' (anonymized) data/schema will make this much clearer.